# ¿Por qué no se envía el formulario con Flask?

Tags: python, web, email, flask, backend

Estuve intentando durante bastante tiempo hacer un formulario de envío de correo con Flask y no se por qué no anda. Utilicé cosas como WTForms y demás. No es que me salga un error en concreto, sino que yo utilizo el botón de submit y lo único que hace es refrescarse la página, no envía nada, no sale error de nada, solo quedan los campos de los inputs con el texto que uno pone. (Soy nuevo en Flask y ni utilizando CHATGPT he podido comprender jaja, si ven comentarios por ahí es que he tenido que pedirle ayuda y así me daba el código)

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('home') }}">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20, class="form-control") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.email.label }} {{ form.email(size=40, class="form-control") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.message.label }} {{ form.message(cols=30, rows=10, class="form-control") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
            </div>
        </form>
```

FORMS.PY

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email


class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Nombre", validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField("Correo electrónico", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    message = TextAreaField("Mensaje", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Enviar")
```

ROUTES.PY

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from app import app
from .forms import ContactForm
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Obtén los datos del formulario
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        msg = form.message.data

        # Configura los detalles del correo electrónico
        sender_email = email  # Reemplaza con tu dirección de correo
        sender_password = "Aquí puse mi contraseña"  # Reemplaza con tu contraseña de correo
        recipient_email = "goldleond387@gmail.com"  # Reemplaza con la dirección de correo del destinatario
        subject = "Nuevo mensaje de contacto"
        body = f"Nombre: {name}\nCorreo electrónico: {email}\nMensaje: {msg}"

        # Envía el correo electrónico
        try:
            with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as smtp:
                smtp.starttls()
                smtp.login(sender_email, sender_password)

                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                msg["From"] = sender_email
                msg["To"] = recipient_email
                msg["Subject"] = subject

                msg.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

                smtp.send_message(msg)

            flash(
                "¡Gracias por tu mensaje! Nos pondremos en contacto contigo pronto.",
                "success",
            )
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
        except Exception as e:
            flash(
                "Ocurrió un error al enviar el correo electrónico. Inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.",
                "error",
            )

    return render_template("index.html", title="Contacto", form=form)
```